# Jquery .children() -- parent has unique class, child has nonunique class, select child

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, parent

I have a form generated by a CRM.

```
  <fieldset><legend>Publish Name in Newspaper
  </legend>
<div class="crm-section custom_67-section"><div class="label"><label>  Check here if we may release your name and contribution levels 
 <span class="crm-marker" title="This field is required.">*</span>
</label></div>
<div class="content">
<input value="1" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1_20" name="custom_67" class="form-radio" />
<label for="CIVICRM_QFID_1_20">Yes</label>&nbsp;
<input value="0" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_0_22" name="custom_67" class="form-radio" />
<label for="CIVICRM_QFID_0_22">No</label></div>
<div class="clear"></div></div></fieldset>
```

Since the class "label" is used repeatedly elsewhere in the form, I need to just select the `div class='label'` inside the `div class="crm-section custom_67-section"`.

This is what I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(.'crm-section custom_67-section').children(.'label').attr("style","width:500px;");
});
```

Comment: The `.` goes inside the string. `'.crm-section.custom_67-section' '.label'`

Comment: `jQuery('.crm-section custom_67-section')`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple class selector for the same element uses multiple dots.

```
jQuery('.crm-section.custom_67-section')
```

`.'` is also invalid syntax .. should be `'.` instead.

Finally, you should use `.css` to set styles rather than updating the style attribute.

Comment: Thanks! Its been a long day and sometimes the easiest solution evades.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('.crm-section custom_67-section .label').attr("style","width:500px;");});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, dots goes inside  '...' : `$('.yourClass')`

Second, when one element have 2 class, you need a dot for each class and no space : `.crm-section.custom_67-section`

Third, dots are the way to select class on html nodes. ex :

```
<div class='hello'> --> $('.hello')
```

Labels arent class, so the get them you need to write `children('label')`

At last, instead of `attr('style', 'width : 400px')` , write `css('width' , '400px')

Final code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.crm-section.custom_67-section').children('label').css('width',"500px;");
});
```